P2P Connection with ICE-SERVER
I would like to try to create 2 HTML pages that exchange  data between them, one transmits the audio, while the other receives the audio and plays it in the second HTML page, without using an actual server.
I tried to look online, but I didn't understand much 

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I believe you want to create two HTML pages where one is the sender and the other is the receiver.Do you want to add the audio files as a media embedding or you want to initiate your device's microphone for audio recording.
As you mentioned, you may not need an actual server as you can just set up a webRTC API (web Real Time Communication) that allows you establish a peer-to-peer communication between the two HTML pages. The most commonly used protocol for this is the ICE protocol (Interactive Connectivity Establishment).
Let me share an example of how you can set up the sender and receiver HTML pages.
Create a sender.html file as shown below:


<body>
    <audio id="local" autoplay muted></audio>
    <button onclick="start(this)">Start Audio</button>
    <button id="stream" onclick="stream(this)" disabled>Broadcast Audio</button>
  
    <script>
      // get audio elements
      const local = document.querySelector("audio#local");
      let peerConnection;
  
      const channel = new BroadcastChannel("stream-audio");
      channel.onmessage = e => {
        if (e.data.type === "icecandidate") {
          peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(e.data.candidate);
        } else if (e.data.type === "answer") {
          peerConnection?.setRemoteDescription(e.data);
        }
      }
  
      
      // functon to start the audio and ask for permission to access microphone
      const start = async (e) => {
        e.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("stream").disabled = false;  // enable the stream button
        await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
          .then((stream) => local.srcObject = stream);
      }
  
      const stream = async (e) => {
        e.disabled = true;
  
        const config = {};
        peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);  // local peer connection
  
        // add an ice candidate event listener, 
        peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", e => {
          let candidate = null;
          
          // prepare a candidate object
          if (e.candidate !== null) {
            candidate = {
              candidate: e.candidate.candidate,
              sdpMid: e.candidate.sdpMid,
              sdpMLineIndex: e.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            };
          }
          channel.postMessage({ type: "icecandidate", candidate });
        });

  
        // add media tracks to the peer connection
        await local.srcObject.getTracks()
          .forEach(track => peerConnection.addTrack(track, local.srcObject));
          
  
        // Create an offer and send through the browser channel, this is necessary to establish a connection (handshake)
        peerConnection.createOffer({ offerToReceiveAudio: true })
          .then(async offer => {
            await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
            channel.postMessage({ type: "offer", sdp: offer.sdp });
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>



Create a receiver.html file as shown below:


<body>
    <audio id="remote" controls></audio>    
    <script>
      // get audio elements
      const remote = document.querySelector("audio#remote");
      let peerConnection;
  
      const channel = new BroadcastChannel("stream-audio");
      channel.onmessage = e => {
        if (e.data.type === "icecandidate") {
          peerConnection?.addIceCandidate(e.data.candidate)
        } else if (e.data.type === "offer") {
          handleOffer(e.data)
        }
      }
  
      const handleOffer = async (offer)  =>{
        const config = {};
        peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
        peerConnection.addEventListener("track", e => remote.srcObject = e.streams[0]);
        peerConnection.addEventListener("icecandidate", e => {
          let candidate = null;
          if (e.candidate !== null) {
            candidate = {
              candidate: e.candidate.candidate,
              sdpMid: e.candidate.sdpMid,
              sdpMLineIndex: e.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            }
          }
          channel.postMessage({ type: "icecandidate", candidate })
        });
        await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer)
          .then(() => peerConnection.createAnswer())
          .then(async answer => {
            await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
            channel.postMessage({
              type: "answer",
              sdp: answer.sdp,
            });
          });
      }
    </script>
  </body>



Create both of these html file and open to the sender.html page. Start the audio and broadcast the audio from that html page. Open the receiver.html file on another window or page on the same browser.
I hope I have been able to help!

Yep, Thanks for the help, now it works between browser tabs.
Sorry for not being clear before, but since I'm building a https server with nodeJS, I need this to work not only inside the same machine but also on other machines.
for example:
I start it from my local pc and then I log in from my phone and the audio needs to be transmitted to the phone.
Again Thanks for your help.
